# How to access windows administrative share from mingw shell?

Tags: windows, shell, git, network-shares, mingw

I am using a mingw shell that comes with github by default, I've been accessing my server's administrative share by:

```
\\myserver\c$\path\to\dir
```

Is there a way to access it from `mingw` shell without having the folder mapped as a network drive in my PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a straight forward answer.

Yes there is:

```
//myserver/c$/path/to/dir
```

Comment: You should mark your answer as answered if you solved the issue.

Comment: I tried, it says I have to wait for 2 days before I can do that :(